# What is SFLIconTool?

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, osx-lion, osx-leopard

I came across a process called SFLIconTool. Its Unix executable is in the following location:

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/Support

Does anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2434737?start=0&tstart=0) may help; it seems to suggest it's something to do with icons.

Running a strings command on the Tool returns the following:

```
com.apple.sidebarlists
systemitems
com.apple.recentitems
.LSSharedFileList
com.apple.loginitems
SessionItems
com.apple.privilegedlist(1)
Icon
@(#)PROGRAM:SFLIconTool  PROJECT:OSServices-
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/OSServices.framework/Versions/A/Support
```

As far as I can gather it seems icon-related but I'm not %100 sure what it does.

Answer (score 0):

I am using it to add a link to a students network home folder to the finder sidebar favorite items.

Apple Script ran from start up Launch Agent:
set userName to short user name of (system info)
do shell script "sftool add-item com.apple.LSSharedFileList.FavoriteItems file:/Volumes/Home" & userName

The problem I have is it is adding another link each time.
Sierra (and i think also El Capitan at least) auto mounts a link to the users network home folder and places a globe icon link in the dock which is a relief.

I have been looking after our macs at a college for the past two years. We have had lots of problems running the Adobe CC suite and other apps with a users library, Docs etc. are saved to a smb share. Lots of crashing, hanging, slowness.  Getting users to log in with a network account but have the system set up their core stuff like Library locally works great. The only issue is how easy our students might save to the local Documents/Desktop instead of their network home drive so a link to their home drive in finder helps them when saving from any app as their network home folder is available to select as a place to save to.